# What is the runtime when using a List or Array as your key in a Hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, list, hashmap, hashcode

A hashmap will return values in O(1) time.  That's why we use it.

But comparing two arrays or lists should occur in O(N) time, where N is the length of those lists, as we need to look up N elements for comparison.

So what happens when we use a list/array as the key for a Hashmap.  Does the hashmap indexing make up for the inefficiency in comparing lists?  Or does the hashcode function now run in O(M) time (M being the length of the list used as the key).

If it does run in O(M) as I suspect, what's the better approach when you need to map a value by a list of keys, rather than a single key?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using something like `HashMap<ArrayList<K>,V>`:  Here's how it works.

When you add a (key, value) pair to the list, it computes the hash code of the key.  The hash code of an `ArrayList` is computed using a formula that looks at the hash codes of all elements on the list.  Thus, if you have two `ArrayList`s with elements that are equal (i.e. the `equals()` method on the elements return true, which means that the hashCode() methods must return the same value), the `ArrayList`s will return the same `hashCode`.  This hash code is then converted to an index into the hash array, which identifies one hash *bucket*, and the key is added to a list of keys for the bucket.  (Ideally, the hash table should be large enough so that those lists of keys are usually no more than 1 in length.)

When you search for a key, `HashMap` computes the hash code of the key.  As noted above, this looks at every element of the list and is therefore O(N) where N is the length of the list.  This is again converted to an index which identifies one hash bucket.  This bucket has a list of keys.  The key is then compared to each key in the "bucket list" (I need to think of a better term for that) using `equals()`; `equals()` must look at each element of both keys, which is another O(N).  Assuming it finds the key it's looking for, it can then retrieve the value.  You can't get by without comparing the keys using `equals()`, because it is possible for two lists that aren't equal to have the same hash code.

So a hash lookup still must go through every element of the `ArrayList` in order to check the keys for equality.  You could perhaps make the hash code computation constant by setting up a wrapper class that keeps a running hash code, but it's generally impossible to eliminate checking every element for equality.  If you could come up with a hash function that's a 1-to-1 correspondence, so that an equal hash code means equal lists, then you could eliminate that O(N).  But in general you can't do this, unless there are some severe constraints on what kinds of data will go into the lists.  In that case, it may be possible to come up with a way to make `equals()` a simple hash code comparison.  But it's unlikely to be worth the effort.  If the lists are short, the O(N) isn't anything to worry about; and if they're long, it's going to be impossible to come up with a function like that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, because every object has it's own signature, the mapping will be built base on that, and the face that your key is in fact a list or an array, doesn't matter. The time will be then O(1) approximately.
So, what you suggested is a good approach if you can actually retrieve easily (and fast) your list.

Some extra:
The way a hash map works is that it has some function - hash function, that can be built automatically or manually, based on your object ID (your key), and for every different object, it should get you a number. this number is resolved to your value. Like that, you'll have more or less an O(1) search for your value with a specific key.

Comment: I don't think this is right.  It may take O(1) time to find the right index in the hash array.  But after it finds the right index, it still needs to compare the keys--finding the index isn't enough.

Comment: Does the fact that each list has it's own signature mean that a different list, with the same elements within it, would not work as an equivalent key?

Comment: @gravityplanx A `HashMap` uses `equals()` to determine whether the keys are equal (after it finds the right bucket), and `equals()` returns `true` if all corresponding elements of the two lists are equal.  I don't know what this answer means by "signature".

Comment: @ajb - which keys does it need to compare? after finding the right index, that's it.

gravityplanx - it depends on how you implement your hash function. It may, or may not.

Comment: @user3730363 sorry, but I don't think you understand how hash tables work.